# Conjugation of Representation of Fundamental Group?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry

I have been studying the correspondence between the space of flat connections $\mathcal{A}_{F}$ of $G$-bundles on a Riemann surface $X$ modulo gauge transformations, and the representations of the fundamental group of $X$ in $G$ where you quotient by the action of congujating by $G$.  Now, once we define a map

$$\Psi: \mathcal{A}_{F} \to \rm{Hom}(\pi_{1}(X), G),$$

as well as its inverse, the next important claim is that these maps descend to the quotients where you mod out by gauge transformations on the flat connections, and quotient by $G$ in the representations where $G$ acts by conjugation.

My question is, how do we define this action of $G$ by conjugation on $\rm{Hom}(\pi_{1}(X), G)$?  Does it depend at all on the fundamental group?  Or is it simply what you would guess: for $\rho, \sigma \in \rm{Hom}(\pi_{1}(X), G)$, identify the two representations if there exists $g \in G$, such that $\rho(x)=g \sigma(x) g^{-1}$, for all $x \in \pi_{1}(X)$?  I'm guessing it's some totally natural thing like this, and then one proves remarkably that it's compatible with quotienting by gauge transformations, giving you the nice correspondence.

Comment: Yes, your guess is correct. However, you should be aware of the fact that for a noncompact group G the quotient tends to be non-Hausdorff.

Comment: Great, thank you.  I'm sorry if this is too off topic, but the reason I doubted my guess above, is that I cannot see how this sort of conjugation arises from gauge transformations acting on the connection.  Given a flat connection $A$, we get $\rm{hol}_{A}: \pi_{1}(X) \to G$.  A gauge transformation is $\Gamma \in C^{\infty}(\Sigma, G)$ where $\Sigma$ is Riem surf.  So $\Gamma$ delivers a different group element for each point in base.  How does one recover the group element you conjugate the representation by?

Comment: See for instance [Eugene Xia, *Abelian and non-abelian cohomology*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.5025v1.pdf).

Comment: @spietro The element you end up conjugating by is the value of the gauge transformation at the basepoint.